# What is causing EF Core to retrieve data much slower then the actual SQL Query and suggestions to speed up?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When running a multi join EF Core query against a context to a DB I get my return data in about 20 seconds (This is running the query thru LinqPad or actual code). When I take the actual SQL generated and run that against the same DB either in LinqPad or SSMS the query returns the results in 3 seconds.  I understand that there is going to be some overhead in EF but is there anyway to speed or optimize the EF query to speed that up? The EF query loads data into context for further use.

```
 _context.Organizations
                .Where(predicate)
                .Include(a => a.OrganizationType)
                .Include(a => a.OrganizationLicenses)
                .Include(a => a.Contacts)
                .ThenInclude(b => b.Phones.Where(p => p.IsActive))
                .ThenInclude(a => a.PhoneType)
                .Load();
```

Comment: What is the actual query you compare against? How much data is being transferred? LinqPad uses EF too, so the difference may be due to loading too much data over a slow connection. Even 3 seconds is a lot for ORM queries meant to load only a few objects and their dependencies.

Comment: Correct indexes can help a ton.

Comment: This query will track every object it loads for changes. If you want to just display the data, tracking is only addiing overhead. You can use `AsNoTracking` to load the data without change tracking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#split-queries-1), instead of generating one big query, eg:

```
  _context.Organizations
          .Where(predicate)
          .Include(a => a.OrganizationType)
          .Include(a => a.OrganizationLicenses)
          .Include(a => a.Contacts)
          .ThenInclude(b => b.Phones.Where(p => p.IsActive))
          .ThenInclude(a => a.PhoneType)
          .AsSplitQuery()
          .Load();
```

which is intended primarily to reduce the load on the database engine by sending simpler queries, but a side-effect is that EF doesn't have to extract multiple entities from a single tabular result.